# Is there a way to add a chrome extension to an already built electron app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron, microsoft-teams

Taking as an example Microsoft Teams app (which as today is still Electron based), in its Developper mode you get to access the dev tools, so, I did [check Electron's docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension) on how to add Chrome extensions, but naturally it only mentions the case when you are the one building the electron app, not when the app is already built.

I'm trying to add [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) extension, macOS Catalina v10.15.7, Microsoft Teams v1.4.00.16567

EDIT:

It is for the local developing & debugging of an app that would be distributed for use inside an electron app, I have no need to add the extension on production it would be for dev-only.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the intended use?     DISCLAIMER: This tool circumvents CORS security rules baked into every browser and is intended for testing your own website during development. Some production websites like Google Docs or Facebook may complain if they detect something that isn't expected. You can use the whitelist feature to only turn on for some domains. To avoid security issues, it is recommend to turn off after debugging.

Comment: @JosVerlinde Hello, yes, it is for the local developing & debugging of an app for the teams store, I already use Moesif to test the app inside teams on the browser env (only locally not in production or staging, as I call other local endpoints in dev mode), I need to test it on the desktop version (teams runs in electron as of now), and yes thanks I only whitelist urls (and only when debugging.)

Comment: Sorry, cant help you as your question is more about electron and trying to add tools to a distributed software package Tams, than Teams itself
I personally have not encountered a need to add such tools tools in order to create / test an App prior to submission

Comment: @JosVerlinde fair enough, thanks for your time, yes this is not a regular testing case as the system is more complex to test in terms of which env I test every endpoint I need, the thing is that on teams desktop things are a bit more peculiar to test than on the browser version